# Failed to convert Go file to JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, gopherjs

I am trying to run go files as modules using: https://github.com/sagiegurari/node-go-require and https://github.com/gopherjs

I dont have any errors in my go code but when using the below JS I run into 'Error: Failed to convert Go file to JS'

Here is my nodeJS code:

```
    require('node-go-require');
    //Failing here
    const Phantom = require(__dirname + '/source/cmd/phantom.go').phantom;

    var params = {
        server:null,
        boundIP:null,
        boundPort:null,
        timeOut:null
    }

    //Some other code here to set params

    function start(){

        //determine which parameters have been set by user
        var args = [params.server];

        if(params.boundIP != null){
            args.push(params.boundIP);
        } else {
            args.push("0.0.0.0");
        }

        if(params.boundPort != null){
            args.push(params.boundPort);
        } else {
            args.push(0);
        }

        if(params.timeOut != null){
            args.push(params.timeOut);
        } else {
            args.push(60);
        }

        var p = Phantom.new(...args);

     }
```

Here is my main go file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js"
    "github.com/jhead/phantom/internal/proxy"
)


func main() {

    js.Module.Get("exports").Set("phantom", map[string]interface{}{
        "new": proxy.New,
    })

}
```

Here is the proxy.New function:

```
package proxy

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "time"

    "github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js"
    "github.com/jhead/phantom/internal/clientmap"
    "github.com/jhead/phantom/internal/logging"
    "github.com/jhead/phantom/internal/proto"
    "github.com/tevino/abool"

    reuse "github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport"
)

var idleCheckInterval = 5 * time.Second

type ProxyServer struct {
    bindAddress         *net.UDPAddr
    remoteServerAddress *net.UDPAddr
    pingServer          net.PacketConn
    server              *net.UDPConn
    clientMap           *clientmap.ClientMap
    prefs               ProxyPrefs
    dead                *abool.AtomicBool
}

type ProxyPrefs struct {
    BindAddress  string
    BindPort     uint16
    RemoteServer string
    IdleTimeout  time.Duration
}

func New(BindAddress string, BindPort uint16, RemoteServer string, IdleTimeout time.Duration) *js.Object {

    var prefs = new(ProxyPrefs)
    prefs.BindAddress = BindAddress
    prefs.BindPort = BindPort
    prefs.RemoteServer = RemoteServer
    prefs.IdleTimeout = time.Duration(IdleTimeout) * time.Second

    bindPort := prefs.BindPort

    // Randomize port if not provided
    if bindPort == 0 {
        randSource := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
        bindPort = (uint16(randSource.Int63()) % 14000) + 50000
    }

    // Format full bind address with port
    prefs.BindAddress = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", prefs.BindAddress, bindPort)

    bindAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", prefs.BindAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    remoteServerAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", prefs.RemoteServer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    return js.MakeWrapper(&ProxyServer{
        bindAddress,
        remoteServerAddress,
        nil,
        nil,
        clientmap.New(prefs.IdleTimeout, idleCheckInterval),
        *prefs,
        abool.New(),
    })
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated as I am almost fresh to GO.

Here is what I am working on for context: https://github.com/OliverBrotchie/phantom

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't run something that'd start a server socket in a browser, anyway.

Comment: Its on the back end. Its basically a proxy server that tricks a system into thinking its a lan connection instead of an external one.

Comment: Okay, but why the JS step?

Comment: Because I have created an electron app front for the proxy so that less technically skilled people can still use it.

Comment: Okay. So why not just have the Electron frontend control a Golang process?

Comment: Because I assume the user would have to have Golang installed to run the go code?

Comment: Golang has the happy property of creating fully static binaries. You need only compile Phantom for your target OS/architecture (or OSes) once and distribute the binary with your Electron frontend.

Comment: I have tried that but the binary requires chmod permissions to run on MacOS and Linux and I want this to be as user friendly to novice users as possible. So I would rather find a way to run the go code from within Node without distributing a separate binary for each OS.

Comment: If you need to, you can call [fs.chmod](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback) within your code. chmod is in no way a privileged operation.

Answer (score 0):

you should run the gopherjs manually to see the actual error:
for example:

```
/workspace/go/bin/gopherjs  build /workspace/phantom/source/cmd/phantom.go
```

one issue might be for example that the go runtime is too old or too new.
once you see the issue, most likely the next place to go to for help is the gopherjs github project page at https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs
where you can open issues direclty.

since no-go-require is just a proxy to it (basically to enable seamless node require capability for go files), i wouldn't try to find the issue there.